# Выбор каталога из проводника

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, bootstrap

Проект написан на laravel, на странице необходимо создать кнопку “задать папку” — при клике, открывается проводник. В проводнике пользователь выбирает папку. Адрес выбранной папки вставляется в поле.

Просмотрел множество источников, но не нашел подходящей информации. Может кто-то подскажет как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Никак. Браузер не даст.

Comment: @Qwertiy , а можете немного подробнее описать почему? может есть ссылка на документацию, где описывается это. Я когда гуглил видел, что многие пишут, что нельзя выбрать каталог, но так и не нашел объяснение почему.

Comment: А зачем вам в браузере выбирать каталог на машине пользователя?

Comment: @VTT нужно, чтобы в текстовом поле отображался путь к папке клиента (этот путь можно написать вручную и с помощью кнопки "задать папку"), там будут хранится файлы, http://prntscr.com/m4th31, там же будет кнопка открыть, которая должна открыть папку в проводнике.

Comment: А вы в курсе, что со страницы у вас отсутствует доступ к файловой системе пользователя? Т.е. нельзя выполнять никакие файловые операции. И тем более запускать произвольные процессы типа проводника. А то при заходе на любой сайт весь жесткий диск бы забивался малварью. Может вам надо выбрать каталог на сервере или какой-то абстрактный каталог?

Comment: @VTT , выбор каталога должен осуществляется по принципу выбора файла http://prntscr.com/m4tzuw , исходя из того, что вы написали, получается, что нельзя выбрать каталог и путь к нему поместить в текстовое поле, так как отсутствует доступ к файловой системе пользователя?

Comment: @Ivan сайт и файловая система пользователя вообще никак не контактирует. Через браузер нельзя работать с файлами пользователей на их компьютере. Это впринципе невозможно.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev , мне не нужно контактировать с файлами на машине пользователя, мне нужно только получить полный путь к директории, которую он выбрал, и сохранить в текстовое поле.

Comment: @Ivan это невозможно. В этом даже нет никакой логики. Даже если теоретически вы получили путь. то зачем он вам? Если вы с ним сделать ничего не сможете.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev , этот путь нужен, чтобы потом при нажатии на кнопку "Открыть" у пользователя открывался проводник с данным каталогом https://prnt.sc/m4th31.

Comment: @Ivan это сделать нельзя, все современные браузеры не позволяют это делать. Эта возможность потенциальная угроза безопасности. Все угрозы были закрыты путём запрета контакта с файловой системой компьютера.

Comment: Можно сделать по-хитрому через input type="file".Но вы все равно не сможете через браузер что-то делать в файловой системе пользователя

Comment: @ArturHan , мне не надо ничего делать в файловой системе пользователя, мне просто нужно сохранить путь, который он указал, а потом по кнопке открыть его в проводнике

Comment: @ArturHan , если знаете какой-то вариант, то будет интересно посмотреть, если не сложно скиньте ссылку или покажите код

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<label for="files">Мой текст</label>

<input id="path" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
<p id="directory"></p>
```

css

```
label{
 width:80px;
 height:40px;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:5px;
}
```

js

```
$('label').click(function(event){
        $('#path').click();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
$('#path').on('change',function(e){
  var dir=$(this).val().split('\')[0];
  $('#directory').text(dir);
});
```

Comment: использовал этот код, получилось следующее http://prntscr.com/m5bb3r, т.е. выбор происходит не каталога, а файла, и путь вставляется довольно странный

Comment: Исправил там обратная косая черта